# Fullcalendar using templates render problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, fullcalendar

I am attempting to use `fullcalendar.io` using `underscore.js` templates. I am only able to load the calendar on a page reload. When a user switches to another template after a click the calendar will not display. I have tried using the destroy, render with no success. I am stuck. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');


<!--- Template for Calendar --->
<script type="text/template" id="calendar-list-template">
    <div id='calendar'><% console.log('cal div'); %></div>
    <% 
    calVars = {}; 
    var passedCalVars = [];
    _.each(calendars, function(calendar) { 
        var obj = { title: calendar.get('title'), start: calendar.get('start') };           
        passedCalVars.push(obj)
    });
     $(function() {
      console.log('fullcal');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            aspectRatio: 1.55,
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: passedCalVars
        });    
    });

  %>
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `#calendar` is in the DOM when you try to do things with `$('#calendar')`? All the `fullCalendar` calls should be in your view and they should probably be `this.$('#calendar').fullCalendar()` calls in `render` and `remove`.

Comment: That was the solution. I moved my code out of the template file into the model file. Thank you